# PHP integration Youtrack

Tags: php, rest, youtrack

Has anyone tried connecting php curl code to youtrack?
I've have done login but not sure how to preserve session for further request like getting issue info, etc. Here my code :

```
$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL,"http://xxxx.myjetbrains.com/youtrack/rest/user/login");
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, "login=xxxx&password=xxxx");

curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
$server_output = curl_exec ($ch);
curl_close ($ch);

var_dump($server_output);
die();
```

Please see https://confluence.jetbrains.com/display/YTD6/Log+in+to+YouTrack
Thanks in davance

Comment: Look into `CURLOPT_COOKIEJAR` etc.

Comment: Isn't it the REST API provide a token for further communication after login? You should use that instead of session, right?

Comment: after doing the above code, no session id :( anyway I'm trying to use CURLOPT_COOKIEJAR

Comment: There are working samples available on github: https://github.com/jan0sch/YouTrack-Client-PHP-Library